# MS Access: use of Not Like on multiple column is now working

Tags: ms-access

I have a very simple table (as exemple)

```
table       period
nok         1
nok         2
nok         3
nok         2
ok          1
ok          2
ok          3
```

I need a query that showns all data but "nok" AND "1"

The result should be:

```
table       period
nok         2
nok         3
nok         2
ok          1
ok          2
ok          3
```

The query I wrote is the following:

```
SELECT Table1.table, Table1.period
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.table)<>"nok") AND ((Table1.period)<>"1"));
```

but the result is:

```
table      period
ok         2
ok         3
```

I looks like the query applied a OR instead of a AND.

The query is so simple that this unexpected result makes me crazy ;)

Where is the mistake?

I also tried with

```
SELECT Table1.table, Table1.period
FROM Table1
WHERE ((Not (Table1.table)="nok") AND (Not (Table1.period)="1"));
```

or

```
SELECT Table1.table, Table1.period
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.table) Not Like "nok") AND ((Table1.period) Not Like "1"));
```

with the same wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the rows without `"nok" AND "1"`, which can be written as:

```
WHERE NOT (Table1.table = "nok" AND Table1.period = "1")
```

and this is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (Table1.table <> "nok" OR Table1.period <> "1")
```

Comment: It works :)
But I don't understand why it's working with OR and not AND!
I though that the query will show everything which is not "nok" nr not "1" and returning only OK 2 and OK 3 (that were the initial wrong data from my query)

Thanks anyway

BTW thanks for the formating

Comment: Think of it like this: you want all rows where **at least one of the columns** `table` and `period` is **not** equal to the values that you reject. This means that either `table` **or** `period` (or both) must not be equal to that value.

Comment: Now how can I reject "NOK 1" and "OK 2" from the results?

Comment: `NOT (Table1.table = "nok" AND Table1.period = "1") AND NOT (Table1.table = "ok" AND Table1.period = "2")`